# Android Application update without Uninstall?

Tags: android

I have developed android application but some issue in my app so I have to give user update but not update I have tested and my application not in play store so how can give an update?
without old app uninstall please help me I have tried for this problem

Comment: Your question doesn't contain proper information. Try to edit it and write properly.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new apk with updated version signed with same `keystore` or if it was a `debug` apk then create from same System you have created the previous one(it is signed with your system keystore). It will update the existing apk without losing any data.

Answer (score 0):

If you send users new apk with new version, Android automatically update app and not delete it. And it save all users data.

Comment: i have try but not woking, and my old version not Enabled "minifyEnabled true", but i have Enabled true in new version so that's time problem so please help another way...i tried

Comment: You don't need enable minifyEnabled. Why this is not working? You need to send new apk on android device with old version and just start normal install. Android update your app by itself.

Comment: I think it have only 1 way - set minifyEnabled false in new version too.

Comment: no i have required to enable so and i have try your solution but not working but not working